# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in runnable jar exported by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar, apache-commons

I am using Eclipse to export my project into a runnable jar.

I'm using a few libraries, namely Apache commons, Java FX, and GSON.

I have added those libraries to my Build Path inside Eclipse:
  [image: screenshot of Eclipse Java Build Path]

When exporting, I choose to package the required libraries into the generated jar:
[image: screenshot of Eclipse export to runnable jar]
This creates a jar called Editor.jar

However when I do "java -jar Editor.jar" I get the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for the class EqualsBuilder which is a part of Apache commons.

I've tried copying the apache commons-lang3-3.4.jar file into the working directory.  I've also tried adding "-cp commons-lang3-3.4.jar" before the "-jar".  Still I always get the ClassNotFoundException.

Does anyone see what I'm missing?  Thanks.

Comment: Open Editor.jar using any extract toola and check if third party jars are available within your jar. If yes, check the path for Rsrc-Class-Path: . and 
Class-Path: . in MANIFEST.MF file of your jar.

Comment: @Leozeo Thanks for the response.  Upon opening the jar I saw that the GSON and FX jar's had been included but not the Apache Commons jar.  I wonder why?  I went back to the Build Path and added the jar as an External Jar and now the deployed build works.  However Apache Commons now appears twice in my Build Path in Eclipse, once as an added "Library" and once as an added "External Jar".

Comment: As a general rule, when using Eclipse should I always add external libraries as both a Library and an External Jar?

Answer (score 1):

Select that option while exporting , If u dont select that option then u might have to resolve the dependencies on your own using `-cp`

[image]